# JavaFX tip calculator slider

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to learn to use JavaFX and scene builder, however I've run into a problem while trying to get a tip calculator to work, in that I'm trying to get it so that when I move the slider to change the tip percentage, the tip amount, and total would automatically change, without needing to click the calculate button, here is code, and a picture of the app! any help is appreciated!

[image: Tip Calculator]

```
package tipcalculator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author joshd
 */
public class TipCalculatorController {

    private static final NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat percent
            = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    private BigDecimal tipPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.15);
    @FXML
    private TextField amountTextField;
    @FXML
    private Label tipPercentageLabel;
    @FXML
    private Slider tipPercentageSlider;
    @FXML
    private TextField tipTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField totalTextField;

    @FXML
    private void calculateButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());
            BigDecimal tip = amount.multiply(tipPercentage);
            BigDecimal total = amount.add(tip);
            tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
            totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            amountTextField.setText("Enter amount");
            amountTextField.selectAll();
            amountTextField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                tipPercentage = BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
                tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
            }
        }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: as I said in my post, I'm trying to get it, so that when I move the slider, it automatically updates the total and tip amounts, without needing to press the "calculate" button, however no matter what I try, it either doesnt work at all, or gets me an argument mismatch error.

Comment: You need to show us your attempt and explain what exactly doesn't work. What happens if you just copy and paste the code from `calculateButtonPressed` to `tipPercentageSlider`'s listener?

Answer (score 2):

Add listeners to the `text` property of `amountTextField` and the `value` property of `tipPercentageSlider` that update the calculation. Furthermore you could use a binding to set the text of `tipPercentageLabel`:

```
private static final NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static final BigDecimal HUNDRED = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);

@FXML
private TextField amountTextField;
@FXML
private Label tipPercentageLabel;
@FXML
private Slider tipPercentageSlider;
@FXML
private TextField tipTextField;
@FXML
private TextField totalTextField;

private void update() {
    BigDecimal amount;
    try {
        amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        tipTextField.setText("Invalid Input");
        totalTextField.setText("Invalid Input");
        return;
    }
    BigDecimal tipFactor = BigDecimal.valueOf(tipPercentageSlider.getValue()).divide(HUNDRED, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal tip = amount.multiply(tipFactor);
    BigDecimal total = amount.add(tip);
    tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
    totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
}

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    // assuming slider value = 100 -> 100%
    tipPercentageLabel.textProperty().bind(tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().asString("%.0f %%"));

    currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(o -> update());
    amountTextField.textProperty().addListener(o -> update());
}
```